# Pandas take number out string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In my data, I have this column "price_range".

Dummy dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price_range': ['€4 - €25', '€3 - €14', '€25 - €114', '€112 - €146', 'No pricing available']})
```

I am using pandas. What is the most efficient way to get the upper and lower bound of the price range in seperate columns?

Comment: Do not use pictures of data, instead give a small dummy dataset which can be copied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively, you can parse the string accordingly (if you want to limits for each row, rather than the total range:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price_range': ['€4 - €25', '€3 - €14', '€25 - €114', '€112 - €146']})



def get_lower_limit(some_string):
    a = some_string.split(' - ')
    return int(a[0].split('€')[-1])
    
def get_upper_limit(some_string):
    a = some_string.split(' - ')
    return int(a[1].split('€')[-1])
    
df['lower_limit'] = df.price_range.apply(get_lower_limit)
df['upper_limit'] = df.price_range.apply(get_upper_limit)
```

Output:

```
Out[153]: 
   price_range  lower_limit  upper_limit
0     €4 - €25            4           25
1     €3 - €14            3           14
2   €25 - €114           25          114
3  €112 - €146          112          146
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following. First create two extra columns `lower` and `upper` which contain the lower bound and the upper bound from each row. Then find the minimum from the `lower` column and maximum from the `upper` column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'price_range': ['€4 - €25', '€3 - €14', '€25 - €114', '€112 - €146', 'No pricing available']})

df.loc[df.price_range != 'No pricing available', 'lower'] = df['price_range'].str.split('-').str[0]
df.loc[df.price_range != 'No pricing available', 'upper'] = df['price_range'].str.split('-').str[1]

df['lower'] = df.lower.str.replace('€', '').astype(float)
df['upper'] = df.upper.str.replace('€', '').astype(float)

price_range = [df.lower.min(), df.upper.max()]
```

Output:

```
>>> price_range
[3.0, 146.0]
```